# Movie with young man with amnesia, and machine to restore memory

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this long ago on TV in the 90s, not sure when the movie came out.

- Its in color...
- Cant say its in English - maybe is even some European language...
- Don't remember any actor/actresses...
- Maybe that's movie some soft Sci-Fi... because i remember one scene that looks like from Sci-fi movie.
- Cant remember much characters except main male.  But maybe (not 100% sure) that there was one female character in a ''hotel room'' with him i think.

### What I remember:

- There is a younger man, Caucasian, with brown or blonde hair. He can't remember anything, or just a bit... minor fragments.
- In one scene, he attached a bottle to a gun, like a silencer and fastened it with tape... broke through some door and attempted to kill a man. Not sure whether he first argued with him, and whether he killed him.
- Then, he drives for a long distance (I think), and comes to an abandoned building. He enters and finds a large room, with a big screen on the wall, and in the center of room a big... now i don't know how to call it. Some lab furniture, workbench, desk, or even to call it - a cast?  Because when he opens it, there was a mold in it, in the shape of human figure. He lies down in that mold, some things get attached to his body and to his face (my bro says it attached to his face, but I don't remember it)... then some liquid began to enter into him... and the same liquid or another one fills that mold.  Not sure what happens then, but when he exits from that ''liquid/mold'', his memory is back, and he remembers everything. That screen turns on... and I don't remember what was on it.

Can for sure say it's not *Total Recall*, *Paycheck* or *Shattered*.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I bet you *can* remember more. Was the movie in colour? Was it in English? What race/ethnicity was the hero? Was there a villain? Who played the hero/villain? Was there a love interest? Was there any sex/violence  in the film?

Comment: https://youtu.be/dtYdZkPmFoU

Comment: Honestly cant say that i remember anything more.  Not remember are there villain. That i know any actor - i think i will find the movie . Sex/violence... really don't remember. But for this main actor can say that it was caucasian  with a... brown or blue hair.  Gonna edit question with that.

Comment: I first thought of _[The Lawnmower Man](https://imdb.com/title/tt0104692/)_ but I don't think enough things match.

Comment: Its not Lawnmower... i know that movie.

Comment: So it's not even Total Recall?? Old one or new?

Comment: Neither of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the movie I was searching for! It's *[Timebomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timebomb_(1991_film))* (1991)

[image: Front cover of Timebomb Bluray case]

> Mild-mannered watchmaker Eddy Kay (Michael Biehn) runs into a burning building to save a trapped woman and is featured in the news as a result. Watching the news, Colonel Taylor (Richard Jordan) is shocked to see Eddy, whom he had assumed to be dead. A game of cat and mouse begins as Eddy, with the help of psychiatrist Dr. Anna Nolmar (Patsy Kensit), tries to discover his past and why they want him dead.
>
> Eddy and Dr. Nolmar discover that he was part of a secret government program to create assassins. Using various sensory deprivation and brainwashing techniques, the assassins could be sent to infiltrate other organizations and facilities undetected and carry out programmed missions. Eddy manages to capture and interrogate one of the female assassins (Tracy Scoggins), finding out the Colonel's current assassination plan. He then plots to confront Colonel Taylor and put an end to the assassination program once and for all.